# How to preserve the original structure of a word while textmining

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I would like to create a list of words that appear at least two times based on a specific web page.
I succeeded to get the data and to get a list with count per each word but 
I need to retain the words that have  an Upper case to stay this way.Right now the code produces the words list with lower case only.
For example, the word "Miami" turns into "miami" while I need it as "Miami".

How can I get the words in their original structure ?

Attached is the code :

```
library(XML)
web_page <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.larryslist.com/artmarket/the-talks/dennis-scholls-multiple-roles-from-collecting-art-to-winning-emmy-awards/"
                          ,useInternal = TRUE)

doctext = unlist(xpathApply(web_page, '//p', xmlValue))
doctext = gsub('\\n', ' ', doctext)
doctext = paste(doctext, collapse = ' ')

library(tm)
SampCrps<- Corpus(VectorSource(doctext))
corp <- tm_map(SampCrps, PlainTextDocument)

oz <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation, preserve_intra_word_dashes = FALSE) # remove punctuation
oz <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, stopwords("english")) # remove stopwords
dtm <-DocumentTermMatrix(oz)

findFreqTerms(dtm,2) # words that apear at least 2 times
dtmMatrix <- as.matrix(dtm) 
wordsFreq <- colSums(dtmMatrix)
wordsFreq <- sort(wordsFreq, decreasing=TRUE)
head(wordsFreq)
wordsFreq <-  as.data.frame(wordsFreq)
wordsFreq <- data.frame(word = rownames(wordsFreq), count = wordsFreq, row.names = NULL)
head(wordsFreq,50)
```

The same problem occurs when I use this lines of code to get a three word ngram:

```
library(RWeka)
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 3, max = 3))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(oz, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
inspect(tdm)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by default, there is an option in `DocumentTermMatrix()` that lowercases your terms.  Turn this off and you will preserve case.

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(oz, control = list(tolower = FALSE))
colnames(dtm)[grep(".iami", colnames(dtm))]
## [1] "Miami"   "Miami,"  "Miami."  "Miami’s"
```

Here's another way to do it using the **quanteda** package, might be more straightforward:

```
require(quanteda)
# straight from text to the matrix
dfmMatrix <- dfm(doctext, removeHyphens = TRUE, toLower = FALSE, 
                 ignoredFeatures = stopwords("english"), verbose = FALSE)
# gets frequency counts, sorted in descending order of total term frequency
termfreqs <- topfeatures(dfmMatrix, n = nfeature(dfmMatrix))
# remove those with frequency < 2
termfreqs <- termfreqs[termfreqs >= 2]
head(termfreqs, 20)
##      art            I      artists   collecting         work           We   collection   collectors 
##       35           29           19           17           15           14           13           12 
##     What contemporary          The        world           us           It        Miami          one 
##       11           10           10           10           10            9            9            8 
##   always         many         make          Art 
##        8            8            8            7
```

We can see that the case for "Miami" (e.g.) is preserved:

```
termfreqs[grep(".iami", names(termfreqs))]
## Miami Miami’s 
##     9       2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ken Benoit. package quanteda seems great.